# LiveData Room loosing data when going to background

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have a ViewPager with one tab that is retrieving data from Room trough a ViewModel with LiveData objects.

**When I switch to any tab and coming back to the one is showing the list of items everything works perfect but when coming from background I don't know why but I am receiving one list less.**

e.g.  First time I enter into the "List fragment".
I retrieve data from 5 different entities and the 5 list items are shown
Go to Background and Back to "List fragment"
4 list have data but 1 is empty
Go to Background and Back to "List fragment"
3 list have data but 2 are empty
... until is fully empty but then I switch tabs and the list well filled

Thanks for any help.

**ViewModel**

```
class TagsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private var repository: TagsRepository = TagsRepository(application)

private var listText: LiveData<List<Text>> = repository.getAllText()

private var listUrl: LiveData<List<Url>> = repository.getAllUrl()

private var listEmail: LiveData<List<Email>> = repository.getAllEmail()

private var listPhone: LiveData<List<Phone>> = repository.getAllPhone()

private var listLauncher: LiveData<List<Launcher>> = repository.getAllLauncher()



fun getData(): List<BaseTag>{
    var allData= mutableListOf<BaseTag>()

    if (listText.value != null){
        listText.value!!.forEach {
            allData.add(it)
        }
    }

    if (listUrl.value != null){
        listUrl.value!!.forEach {
            allData.add(it)
        }
    }

    if (listEmail.value != null){
        listEmail.value!!.forEach {
            allData.add(it)
        }
    }

    if (listPhone.value != null){
        listPhone.value!!.forEach {
            allData.add(it)
        }
    }

    if (listLauncher.value != null){
        listLauncher.value!!.forEach {
            allData.add(it)
        }
    }

   return allData
}


//-------TEXT--------
fun insertText(text: Text) {
    repository.insertText(text)
}

fun deleteTextByID(id: Int) {
    repository.deleteTextByID(id)
}

fun getAllText(): LiveData<List<Text>> {
    return listText
}

fun deleteAllText() {
    repository.deleteAllText()
}
```

repository getAllText() returns tagsDao.getTextList()
 and Dao is:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Text")
    fun getTextList(): LiveData<List<Text>>
```

**EDIT**

I changed the viewPager to not recreate the fragments again, Observing LiveData in onViewCreated, clearing the list in onPause and setting data again in onResume and adding viewLyfeCycleOwner

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_tags, container, false)
    return v
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupUI()
}

private fun setupUI(){
    val recyclerView = v.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    tagsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TagsViewModel::class.java)

    getTags()

    (activity as MainActivity).mToolbar.onMenuItemClick {
        when (it!!.itemId){
            R.id.btnDeleteAll -> toast("sort")
            R.id.btnOrderBy -> tagsViewModel.deleteAll()
        }
    }
}

private fun getTags(){
    tagsViewModel.getAllText().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer<List<Text>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
    tagsViewModel.getAllEmail().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer<List<Email>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
    tagsViewModel.getAllUrl().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer<List<Url>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
    tagsViewModel.getAllPhone().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer<List<Phone>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
    tagsViewModel.getAllLauncher().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer<List<Launcher>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
}

override fun onPause() {

    adapter.clear()
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onResume() {
    adapter.setTags(tagsViewModel.getData())
    super.onResume()
}
```

and it is working the same than before, when I come back from background in onResume my viewModel is returning always one list less which is totally random, sometimes textList, sometimes emailList... Why it is loosing its data? I have no clue why.

**Edit 2**

```
class TagsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<TagsAdapter.TagHolder>() {

    private var baseList: MutableList<BaseTag> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TagHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.tag_item, parent, false)
        return TagHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TagHolder, position: Int) {
        val tag = baseList[position]
        holder.tvAlias.text = tag.content
        holder.tvDate.text = tag.date?.let { AppUtils.toDate(it) }
        holder.ivType.background = tag.type?.let { getDrawable(it) }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return baseList.size
    }

    fun setTags(list: List<BaseTag>) {
        if (this.baseList.isEmpty()) {
            this.baseList = list as MutableList<BaseTag>
        } else {
            this.baseList.addAll(list)
        }
        orderList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun getDrawable(type: String): Drawable? {
        when (type) {
            AppConstants.TYPE_TEXT -> return ContextCompat.getDrawable(App.instance, R.drawable.ic_text)
            AppConstants.TYPE_EMAIL -> return ContextCompat.getDrawable(App.instance, R.drawable.ic_write)
            AppConstants.TYPE_URL -> return ContextCompat.getDrawable(App.instance, R.drawable.ic_clean)
            AppConstants.TYPE_PHONE -> return ContextCompat.getDrawable(App.instance, R.drawable.ic_mobile)
            AppConstants.TYPE_LAUNCHER -> return ContextCompat.getDrawable(App.instance, R.drawable.ic_code)
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun orderList(){
        baseList.sortBy { it.date }
        baseList.reverse()
    }

    fun clear(){
        this.baseList.clear()
    }

    inner class TagHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvAlias: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlias)
        var tvDate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate)
        var ivType: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivType)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be observing in `onStart` in Activities, and `onViewCreated` in Fragments (using `getViewLifecycleOwner` for Fragments).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did it and it's the same, I updated the question, I am not so sure what is the problem now...

Comment: This is interesting. Possible for you to share a demo project to replicate this?

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not sure why the fragment is behaving in this way--probably need to look at the adapter implemenation--but few things caught my attention:

**`observe` in `onResume` but not cleared in `onPause`**

Even if the adapter is "cleared" in `onPause` state, the observers are not. This means that each time fragment goes to background then foreground, the fragment is creating a new set of observers while previous observers are still alive and observing the same `LiveData`, consequently making the adapter less predictable due to these duplicated observers.

**Using `this` in observing `LiveData`**

`LiveData` observers are unsubscribed when the `LifeCycle` object goes into [DESTROYED](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State.html#DESTROYED) state. This means that in order to avoid observers being duplicated, the observers should be subscribed before `CREATED` state and that's `onCreate` method is `Activity` and `Fragment`. If you don't like this behavior you need to pass in a different `LifeCycleOwner` object.

*1. Use `getViewLifecycleOwner()`*

It is quite impractical to observe in `fragment.onCreate` because fragment's view is not even ready. So Android has this convenient method called `getViewLifecycleOwner()` that can signal `DESTROYED` in `onDestroyView()` phase so that the `Fragment` can observe in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`. You can use it like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(...): View {
    ...
    getTags()
    ...
    return view
}

private fun getTags(){
    tagsViewModel.getAllText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            Observer<List<Text>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
    tagsViewModel.getAllEmail().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            Observer<List<Email>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
    tagsViewModel.getAllUrl().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            Observer<List<Url>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
    tagsViewModel.getAllPhone().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            Observer<List<Phone>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
    tagsViewModel.getAllLauncher().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            Observer<List<Launcher>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
}
```

*2. Use custom `LifeCycleOwner`*

Implement custom `LifeCycleOwner`. I think this [article](https://androidoverride.wordpress.com/2017/05/27/android-working-with-live-data-and-custom-life-cycle-owners/) can help.

**`Fragment` lifecycle in `ViewPager`**

Depends on the `ViewPager` implementation, `Fragment` will not go through `onPause` -> `onResume` state just by switching the tabs. Also, distance between the tabs can also matter. For instance, the `Fragment` will probably not "pause" if you switch to a tab right next to it. Try to log the fragment state to see how switching tabs affect their life cycle.

Comment: Many thanks on your explanation. I am using a ViewPager and TabLayout, Do you think is better to use BottomNavigationView and control the fragment navigation myself? Because I thought when switching tabs the fragment was created just once, but I can see how onCreateView is called again and again. 

I read this article and maybe is my solution..

https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711

Comment: Ah, yeah, fragments will need the newly introduced `setMaxLifecycle` to go to onPaused in an adapter.

Comment: @Pablo R. I don't think you need to switch your design and implementation completely. I think using [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter) is enough to prevent fragment recreation.

Comment: I changed it 2 ways and now at least is not recreating the fragments but as you said that was not my problem. Question edited.

Comment: @Pablo R. It is most likely the adapter problem. Can you show us your adapter implementation?

Comment: @SanlokLee Adapter posted.